# Create a file and let client download on the fly via web browser

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I would like to create and store a csv file onto the clients machine within a specified directory on the fly.

I have a semi-working attempt below however it seems to create and store the file onto the server machine and not the client. I would prefer to not store any files server-side and want to generate the file on the fly, straight into a clients directory.

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
File.WriteAllText(path+fileName.csv, data);
```

Comment: You can't, of course. What if you could overwrite a system DLL witha malicious version?

Comment: I thought that would be the case, thanks @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write file from the server directly into the user's folder, but browser can download it to a download folder or prompt user for a directory, depending on his browser settings. In any case it's out of your control.

If you want to make download, it can be something like this:

```cs
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public MyController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "/myfile.csv");
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            return NotFound();

        return new FileStreamResult(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), "text/csv");
    }
}
```